# Which is the correct way to use @Singleton EJB and multithreading with @Asynchronous?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

Most of business logic of our product consists in many automatic jobs which perform data loading from DB, processing and final persistence. 
Each job is an EJB like the following:

```
@Stateless
@Local(Job.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class JobImpl {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timer;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction transaction;

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @EJB
    private BusinessLogicEJB someDependencyEJB;

}
```

Each job, after is started, is configured to be automatically scheduled every n seconds using EJB TimerService:

```
this.timer.createIntervalTimer(1000, properties.getTimeout(),  new TimerConfig(properties, false));
```

where `properties` is an object wrapping that job configuration. In this configuration it is set up how many items the job is supposed to process at each cycle and if multithreading is allowed. If yes, it is also specified the max number of threads and how many items per thread must be processed.

So, when `@Timeout` annotated method is called, all data waiting to be processed is loaded from DB. If more than max items allowed for a single thread are loaded and if multithreading is enabled, these items are splitted into N threads, each created by

```
this.timer.createSingleActionTimer(0, new TimerConfig(itemsChunk, false));
```

which creates a single execution timer. Then, when all threads are created, the EJB father (class implementing job) waits them to finish:

```
private void waitToComplete(){
    while(timer.getTimers().size() > 2){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Each child process calls `@Timeout` annotated method but it is detected as a child thread and it follows its own branch until it finishes:

```
@Timeout
public void execute(Timer tm) {
    JobProperties properties = (Properties)tm.getInfo();
    if(tm.isSubTask()) {

        List chunk = tm.getElementsToExecute();
        process(chunk);
    }
}
```

where `process()` is a **private** method which can use some other injected business logic EJB or the EntityManager and so on.

Finally, a new schedule time is arisen and everything starts again from the beginning.

Now, I was asked to perform some refactoring and we want out EJB Job class as `@Singleton` while threads processing must not be created by `TimerService` but by `@Asynchronous` annotation.

Is is possible to annotate with `@Asynchronous` a private or a public method of the same EJB (like `process()`) in order to get a new generated thread?

Actually I created a brand new further EJB bean managed transaction with `process()` method which has injected EJB `someDependencyEJB` and uses `UserTransaction` for DB transaction but this is too bug refactoring.

Is there a way to re-use private methods (or made them public) of the `@Singleton` EJB to correctly perform with `@Asynchronous` and without having a "Trasaction already exists" exception each time a new thread is created?

We run or product in Wildfly 10 with EJB 3.1 Java EE 6, and unfortunately we cannot update to Java EE 7.

Comment: The problem might be the local calls of the same bean. In that case the Asynchronous-Annotation works only if you first use the SessionContext and fetch the BusinessObject of your class. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject(java.lang.Class)

Comment: Yes, I’ve come accross some posts about what you’ve written. Anyway I had made another trial as explained [here](https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/java/asynchronous-does-not-work-from-inside-the-same-ejb) But the result is an exception on UserTransaction.begintTransaction() as there is a transaction already in progress. As if a brand new thread was not started at all

Comment: ExecuterBean with or without CMT? If "With CMT" then Usertransaction is not usable. If BMT, I think the container does not know about the transaction and therefore can not suspend it, as the correct behaviour would request. Therefore you will use the same transaction in multiple threads. If the container is good, then he does distributed transactions over multiple connections otherwise you are working on the same db-connection with different threads, that is dangerous! Why do you BMT?

Comment: ExecuterBean was CMT because transaction was supposed to be begun and commutted  by re-calling main singleton bussiness method process()... also because that method is very complex: in case of business logic excaption, transaction is rolled back and another one is started and commited to update items in error state on DB, waiting to be re-processed

Comment: So, shall I use TransactionManagement.NEVER on executer bean?

Comment: As I understood, you tried UserTransaction.begin inside a CMT-Bean. That is not allowed. why do you use BMT?

Comment: In the singleton bean you mean? It was already like that but I think the reason was that even if a business logic exception is raised on loaded DB entities (either from Drools engine or from another injected EJB) than the transaction is rolled back and another one is created to put those entities in error state on DB. In this way, they can be reprocessed by user later. That’s why more transactions are needed according to what happens and with a single CTM it is not possible

Comment: You know that @Requires_New has the same effect.

Comment: Yes but this all these methods are inside the Singleto bean... should I annotate them with Requires_New they do not have any effect if not called from outside the singleton EJB itself. I know some massive refactoring is required on this old bad code but they do not give me too much time...I don’t know if the fastest and securest way it to extract businss logic intona further EJB with @Asynchronous method or if use ExecutorBean without transaction management, delegatinf them back to Singleton EJB

Comment: Do you have tests? Perhaps you can encapsulate the Usertransaction.begin() inside a method and start it only, if it is not started already. You can ask the Usetransaction if it is currently active. That is also bad code and i normally would not recommend it, but perhaps it helps in your case. The usage of Asynchronous should speed up the processing? Did you already experiment with the number of timerthreads, before doing such a structural change?

Comment: I don’t think Asynchrous will speed up the process. According to my architect it was logically incorrect to use the same Timeout-Schedule method which behaves differently according to if timer service is the main or some child single executed one...I’m afraid I’ll have to ask him better tomorrow again. Thank you for your kind replies and advices.

Comment: If you are using WildFly 10 then you have already updated to Java EE 7. It seems to me that you need the JSR352 Batch API